# Is there a function in JavaScript that allows me to show relevant Google Map markers between a starting point and a destination?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have developed a Google Maps application using ASP.NET and JavaScript that allows the user to add a starting address and a destination address in order to view the gas stations that are on that route.

The target of this application is to show the gas stations *on that specific route* to the user.

The coordinates and addresses of *all* gas stations are stored in a database.

What I am having difficulty with is producing a solution which allows me to show only the *relevant* gas station markers and to hide the markers that are *not relevant*.

Relevant, in this context means, on the specific route selected. So, all gas station markers *not on that route*, should be hidden.

Below is a visual example.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se6jd.png)

A is the starting point and B is the destination. Along the blue line, the route, I would like to show the gas stations only between A and B. Any gas station that isn't within A and B should not be shown.

So far, I have checked the below sources but they don't seem to mention something relevant to my problem.

1. https://forums.asp.net/t/2113575.aspx?Display+nearby+markers+on+google+map+base+on+search+result
2. http://abctutorial.com/Post/74/how-to-add-and-show-markerslocation-in-google-map-from-database-in-aspnet-mvc-%7C-jquery
3. http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/asp/how-to-show-markers-location-in-google-map-from-database

Is there some sort of function available that allows me to show just the relevant markers on a route and hide the rest?